# CardView wrapping

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have a card view in my application (using the support libraries) and I want the cards to wrap around if they don't all fit in one row. Currently, they are just stacking vertically. Is there a way to make them not only wrap, but also to fill the whole parent if they're the only element in the list?

Ideally I would like two cards per row and then for them to wrap at that point to a new line.

View containing the recyclerview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/my_rootlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_window"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_headertext"
        style="@style/roboto_header_text_black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/device_padding"
        android:text="@string/en_us_my_header"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".85"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/default_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#99000000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/my_listitem_title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="This is my title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:progress="45" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/code_text_block"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="ABC" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_listitem_id_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="#123456"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_listitem_date_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="Nov 5 - Nov 12, 2016"
        android:textColor="#7D7D7D" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Download"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/download_button"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to use a `GridLayout` as @random6174 [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26536716/2246380), use this [code as guide](https://github.com/rnrneverdies/HeroTransition), it does exactly what you want.

Attention to this part, where it declares the `RecyclerView LayoutManager (MainActivity.java)`:

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use a *flow layout* here. As far as i know Android does not have a built-in flow layout class, but there is plenty of stuff to find elsewhere; for instance [this one](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout).

But then, since you want to display cards which will likely all have the same size, maybe you can also use a `GridLayout` and programmatically adjust the number of columns to fit your needs.

Good luck!

/edit: Nevermind, I just learned what a CardView is. I thought you want to display playing cards. Maybe flow layout is still suited for you, but I surely misunderstood the question. My bad.